# SharePoint 2013 search results hover action not using FQDN

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search

Single server farm, SP 2013 Enterprise.

The search results are for the most part working well and as expected. I have one slight glitch. When you hover over a search result in the items returned, you get the option to **VIEW FOLDER**.

That link is using `https://shortname:port/...`, I want it to use `https://fqdn/...`

The other links in the pop out menu for the hover actions are using the FQDN and working find, just the **VIEW FOLDER** is wrong and of course failing.

I have played around with AAM/Server Name Mappings till I am blue in the face but I can not get this last link to work. Depending on my AAM/Server Name Mapping settings, I can break other stuff like the actual crawl, or I can get all the links in the pop out hover action to be wrong IE using the `shortname:port`.

The way I have them now, the crawls work fine, search result links are fine and all but the **VIEW FOLDER** link is fine in the pop out menu for the hover over a search result.

I am stumped. Any ideas are welcome and appreciated.

Comment: Are you crawling the default zone?  What zones have you set up for each of the above URLs?

Answer (score 1):

Saying you "played around with AAM" worries me. Search always returns results from the same zone that originated the query. If you search from https://server:port (which, I think, you should NEVER do. You should not have your users ever see a port number, IMHO) the results will return from the AAM zone that https://server:port is in, failing that it will revert to default.

That said, you should "align" your AAMs. Set https://fqdn as your default zone for all web applications. Align other zones as needed. Finally, perform a full crawl.

Comment: I have watched your video which clearly explained these. I agree with your points

Comment: Yes, I am using https;//FQDN for the default AAM. However, I am using https://server:port for the crawls with a server name mapping to map to https://fqdn. If I try to use the FQDN for the crawl, it errors out with access denied.

Comment: You must only crawl the default zone. If you are getting access denied you must fix that.